# Can a Facebook fanpage/business account create a Facebook app

Tags: facebook-apps

My Facebook account was opened as a fanpage/business account (not a fanpage as a child from a personal account). Now I want to create an app. The link [developers.facebook.com/apps/](http://developers.facebook.com/apps/) gets redirected to my fanpage.

Does that mean I can't create an app with this account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook only allows accounts that belong to a person to create apps. They do not value a company page as an account that is supposed to anything but promoting themselves. The people behind (which usually are admins) can create apps.

Comment: my experience, too. why doesn't face***k issue at least a warning/message about what's going on?! grrr.