# Should I create a Facebook app for a business page with my personal account

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-apps

A plugin we're using on our website requires us to create a Facebook app and get a Facebook App ID so that users can share a Facebook post from our website after entering a competition draw.

I was able to the a Facebook app easily enough by going to:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Everything is working fine but it seems odd that the app is managed under my personal Facebook account.  I checked with the person who created the Facebook page for the business and they did it from their personal account too.

Is there a better way of doing this so that the Facebook app is not under my own personal account? Are there any costs associated with having a Facebook app like this?

Comment: See also: [Can a Facebook fanpage/business account create a Facebook app](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39072/354), [Why can I not create an application on my Facebook page?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23082/354) and [How to assign an Facebook app created by personal account to a business page?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36593/354)